# Hibernate JPA and Spring javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, spring, jpa

When I call:

```
entityManager.flush()
```

I get the exception mentioned in the title.

I am using Hibernate JPA.

Comment: show your web.xml , and your servlets files

Answer (score 17):

After encountering this problem myself and spending a few hours trying to get it resolved I finally found a reason for it: Spring has a bug and can't maintain transactions with `@Transactional` annotation if the same class has `@Service` annotation for the means of autowiring.

Once the `@Service` annotation was removed from the service class in question, and an appropriate bean was declared in the XML config:

```
<bean id="myService" class="com.example.myapp.service.MyServiceImpl" />
```

the problem is gone.

Check this [JIRA bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5082) for more details.

Comment: Well saying this is a bug is not totally correct, the link you have given already has given good explanation why this is happening - the Service class getting instantiated as a bean in both appContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml. It should only get 'bean'ed in appContext.xml otherwise it won't have transaction support.

Comment: @HarshalWaghmare You saved my bottom twice. I encountered the same error twice and was eagerly trying to find your comment again :D. Finally, hurray. Told servlet-context just to scan controllers.. everything works like charm.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure that you have an active transaction when this statement executes.  If you are using JPA  use EntityManager.getTransaction().begin().  This is assuming that you are using JPA outside a JTA transaction scope.

If you are running the application inside a container with JTA support you can also use JTA UserTransaction to manage transactions.

Comment: "Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead"

Answer (score 4):

My Problem was to do with the way that I setup the `<tx:annotation-driven/>` Element in my context definition -

Originally I had load time weaving enabled (not knownley)  that read     `<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>` and by simply removing the 2nd attribute - everything worked (took 2 hours of head banging though). I believe the 2nd element relates to the @Configurable sterotype but can let other (smarter) people explain the difference & why one would work & the other does does not.. Hope this helps...

working definition= `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>`

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, just add @Transacctional annotation not only on the method, also in the class together with your @Service annotation.

for example:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyService {

}
```

Comment: The @Transactional annotation to the class solved my problem.

Comment: How exactly does it solve the problem? Why `@Transactional` on the method is not enough?

Answer (score 3):

Spring 4.3.1 / Hibernate 4.2.21

My configuration was 100% Java code with no hibernate or spring xml documents (eg context.xml, persistence.xml etc). The issue was the `EntityManagerFactory` I was passing to the `TransactionManager`, see the below configuration in the `transactionManager` method.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfiguration2 {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return ...; // Build a basic datasource
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("nz.co.mark");
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceProviderClass(org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.class);

    return entityManagerFactory;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public EntityManager entityManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) {
    EntityManager em = localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO);
    return em;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf) throws Exception {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf.getObject());
    // The below line would generate javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    // transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf.getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you have an active transaction when this statement executes. If you are using JPA use `EntityManager.getTransaction().begin()`. This is assuming that you are using JPA outside a JTA transaction scope.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem... spent some hours until I found the reason finally.
It was just one line of code that caused the exception in my case...

In my ***mvc-core-config.xml*** the following line was the reason:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package.application" />
```

After I changed it as follows, everything worked again:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package.application.controller" />
```

So I guess the scanning of all my application packages instead of just my @Controller classes lead to the problem like @harshal-waghmare mentioned in [his post to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801828/hibernate-jpa-and-spring-javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-no-tran#comment19875194_3840740).

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your handler method is declared as `public`

```
@Transactional 
@RequestMapping('/test')
public String doTest() {
    // do your stuff here 
    return 'testview';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your spring configuration includes the following line:

`<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`

`mode` can be either *proxy* or *aspectj* and `transaction-manager` has to point to your transaction manager been.

Answer (score 0):

Same was happening to me using spring 3.0.0 / 3.0.3. Data was persisted in MySQL from JUnit but not from the tomcat server. After so much work I gave up on RESOURCE_LOCAL for JTA.

This worked for me http://erich.soomsam.net/2007/04/24/spring-jpa-and-jta-with-hibernate-and-jotm/ It uses JTA and depends on JOTM.

Answer (score 0):

For JBoss 4.0 and Hibernate, I fixed this problem by adding some transaction manager properties to my `EntityManagerFactoryBean` definition:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="xaDs" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

I found the soluton [on this message board thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=44707).

Answer (score 0):

I did all the thing as a following. My problems was with "import" tag,  there are several context root like servlet-context and root-context which are not dependent on each other. It becomes clear with Spring Explorer view in STS. No JTA for Tomcat.

My advice would be universal:  run Pet Clinic on your environment , [How to run Spring 3.0 PetClinic in tomcat with Hibernate backed JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536292/how-to-run-spring-3-0-petclinic-in-tomcat-with-hibernate-backed-jpa)
or generate with Roo stub of application and try to compare your configs with referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fixed this error by adding

```
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="yourTransactionManager" />
```

into my application-context.xml

Comment: Your answer contradicts Ian's answer. He removed the mode="aspectj" parameter.