# How to run Spring 3.0 PetClinic in tomcat with Hibernate backed JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, tomcat6

OK, this probably is supposed to be the easiest thing in the world, but I've been trying for the entire day, and it's still not working.. Any help is highly appreciated!

EDIT: **For the correct procedure, please see Pascal's answer.**

My wrong (since I did not disabled LoadTimeWeaving) procedure is left for reference..:

What I did:

1. Downloaded Tomcat 6.0.26 & Spring 3.0.1
2. Downloaded PetClinic from https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic
3. Built & deployed petclinic.war. Ran fine with default JDBC persistence.
4. Edited webapps/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml and set `jpaVendorAdaptor` to Hibernate.
5. Edited webapps/WEB-INF/web.xml and changed `context-param` from applicationContext-jdbc.xml to applicationContext-jpa.xml
6. Copied everything in the Spring 3.0.1 distribution to TOMCAT_HOME/lib.
7. Launched tomcat. Saw

   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-agent.jar
8. Uncommented line `<Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>` in webapps/META-INF/context.xml.
9. Same error. Added that line to TOMCAT_HOME/context.xml
10. Deployed without error. However, when I do something it will issue an error saying

    `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:39)`

    11.Changed scope of javax.transaction from test to default (just deleted test), as suggested by scaffman.

    12.Runs fine!! Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is at (3). Does the WAR that gets built contain anything from `javax.transaction` in its `lib` directory?

Comment: You didn't use TopLink at 3, you used JDBC

Comment: @Pascal: You're right, I fixed the post..

Comment: @skaffman: I checked the pom.xml and javax.transaction is in test scope.. I'll try including it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, here is what I did:

1. Get Tomcat 6.0.26
2. Checkout the petclinic sample:

   ```
   svn co https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/trunk/ petclinic
   ```
3. `cd` into the petclinic directory
4. Modify `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml` to use Hibernate:

   - COMMENT the `<context:load-time-weaver>` ([load-time weaver **SHOULD NOT** be used with Hibernate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-setup-lcemfb), this is for Toplink)
   - Declare Hibernate as `jpaVendorAdapter` (comment the Toplink part, uncomment the Hibernate part)
5. Modify the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` to use the `applicationContext-jpa.xml`
6. Modify the `pom.xml` to bundle **jta.jar** in the war (as pointed out by @skaffman):

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
     <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.transaction</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.0</version>
     <!--scope>test</scope-->
   </dependency>
   ```
7. Build the war

   ```
   mvn install
   ```
8. Deploy it to Tomcat

   ```
   cp target/petclinic.war $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps
   ```
9. Browse

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/petclinic
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why the manual says "LTW is not necessary with Hibernate". This helps me a LOT!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with PetClinic packaging:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=85042

and

http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6880

There's fix in there for the `pom.xml`