# How to use JPA in spring sample petclinic?

Tags: java, spring, orm, jpa

I am learning spring samples. In the petclinic project, by default it uses jdbc. I change the following line to jpa, and can't run it anymore

```
/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml
```

Here is the error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-agent.jar
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.setBeanClassLoader(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    ... 35 more
```

Any response would be very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default Tomcat class loader does not support class transformation required for Load-Time Weaving. You need to use the one provided by Spring.

First, copy `org.springframework.instrument-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar`  to the `lib` folder of your tomcat installation

Then modify the `src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml` and uncomment the following line:

```
<Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
```

Or you could get rid of the LTW and use Hibernate as JPA provider. See the related question below.

#### See also

- [Spring Load-time Weaving on Tomcat: Does It Really Work?](http://fadishei.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/spring-load-time-weaving-on-tomcat-does-it-really-work/)

#### Related question

- [How to run Spring 3.0 PetClinic in tomcat with Hibernate backed JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536292/how-to-run-spring-3-0-petclinic-in-tomcat-with-hibernate-backed-jpa)

#### References

- [3.12 Registering a LoadTimeWeaver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-load-time-weaver)
- [7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable)
- [7.8.4 Load-time weaving with AspectJ in the Spring Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw)