# Spring + Hibernate init error: Cannot find class [<providername>]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entitymanager

I have been going crazy for a while tonight trying to get a simple project run with Spring MVC and Hibernate in java. Basically I stumbled from one error to another but they were all due to the fact that a jar file was missing, which I resolved promptly adding the dependency into Maven. This worked until this error came up:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource 
    [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [Hibernate]
```

Now, it is strange that the class cannot be found and that the exception is Illegal Argument and not a ClassNotFound or something like that.

I have this set up in the servlet-context

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

and the root-context is:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="emf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
</bean>

<bean id="taskRepo" class="com.leandro.dao.GenericRepository">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>com.leandro.models.Task</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

It is clearly failing to generate the emf bean, which should be injected into the Generic Repo at this line:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}
```

I spent the whole night on this, does anyone have any idea what I may be missing?

UPDATE: as requested, this is the persistence xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="testmvc" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>Hibernate</provider>
        <class>com.leandro.models.Task</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="***"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="***"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=CoveyTMM"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=CoveyTMM"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="***"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="***"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: do you have hibernate in your classpath

Comment: Is it possible to post the persistence.xml too? I think this exception has something to do with that.

Comment: Yes I have Hibernate in the classpath, among the Maven Dependencies. I first added a few hibernate jars manually but then added hibernate-entitymanager to the pom.xml and that carried across all dependencies. @sgp15 I have added the persistence xml to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @sgp15, the problem was in the persistence file. As soon as I added it to the question I noticed that there was something wrong. I changed the line specifying the provider to this:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

And Spring was able to lad it.

PS: as a bonus I noticed that there were other error, one of which was caused by the root-context. I simply deleted this line: `<context:load-time-weaver/>` since I am deploying on tomcat with Hibernate powered JPA: [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536292/how-to-run-spring-3-0-petclinic-in-tomcat-with-hibernate-backed-jpa)