# The transaction with Spring e Jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, transactions

i have the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801828/hibernate-jpa-and-spring-javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-no-trans), my Transactions not write into DB. I think this Spring problem regard is not a bug of framework, but is a problem of configuration file (applicationContext.xml for understand) so I put my configuration file:

```
...    
            <!-- this is a bridge for entityManager and PersistenceUnit -->
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="fb-persistence" />
        </bean>


    <bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"> 
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean name="pluginDaoImpl" class="it.synclab.fb.jpa.dao.impl.PluginDaoImpl" />
</beans>
```

a interface is:

```
public interface PluginDao {

    public Plugin load (int id);

    public void save(Plugin plg);
}
```

a implementation of interface is:

```
public class PluginDaoImpl implements PluginDao {

    @PersistenceContext (unitName="fb-persistence")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Plugin load(int id) {
        return em.find(Plugin.class, id);

    }
    @Transactional(readOnly=false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void save(Plugin plg) {
        em.persist(plg);
        //em.flush();

    }
}
```

and dulcis in fundo, my PluginTest (for dirty-testing) is:

```
public class PluginTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        PluginDao dao = (PluginDao) applicationContext.getBean("pluginDaoImpl");

        Plugin plugin1 = new Plugin();
        //inserisco un nuovo plugin
        //plugin.setId(14);
        plugin1.setMethod("prova");
        plugin1.setDescrizione("questa Bean Class!");
        dao.save(plugin1);

        Plugin plugin = new Plugin();
        //carico un plugin per id
        plugin =  dao.load(9);

        System.out.println("id: " + plugin.getId() + 
                         " Descrizione: " + plugin.getDescrizione() + 
                         " Method: " + plugin.getMethod());
    }
```

If I now add the method PluginDaoImpl.save (), em.flush line-code I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress *
```

*the cause is not specificated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager"/>`
in your context.xml

(See [Using `@Transactional`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations))

Add the tx namespace like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: Line 18 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "tx" for element "tx:annotation-driven" is not bound.

Comment: @giulius then you need to add the tx namespace as well. see my updated answer

Comment: You have collaborated to write Spring :P..thanks, it work, now "persist" into db. For completeness read your link to learn more about Spring. ;)