# TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-data-jpa

I [looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801828/hibernate-jpa-and-spring-javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-no-tran) [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536292/how-to-run-spring-3-0-petclinic-in-tomcat-with-hibernate-backed-jpa) for similar problems but couldn't find a solution for this:

I have a [Spring Data JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) application that whenever I try to do a trasaction I get `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress`.

I believe it has something to do with the Transaction Manager or Entity Manager Factory, but can't put my finger on it.

The context files are [here](https://code.google.com/p/simple-cash/source/browse/?r=17#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fresources) (latest checked in are [here](https://code.google.com/p/simple-cash/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fresources)), but here is the part that matters:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMySQL" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-jpa" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMySQL"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceMySQL" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="pass"/>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.simplecash.dal.repository" />
```

A sample Repository is [here](https://code.google.com/p/simple-cash/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/simplecash/dal/repository/BankRepository.java?r=17) and then created a Repository Factory [here](https://code.google.com/p/simple-cash/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/simplecash/dal/RepositoryFactory.java?r=17), which I'm not sure if I need...
Then use it [here](https://code.google.com/p/simple-cash/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/simplecash/dal/DatabaseManagerDAO.java?r=17#34) (line 34).

```
public void populateWithTestData() {

    Bank bank = new Bank();
    bank.setName("ContentName");
    bank.setCode("ContentCode");

    RepositoryFactory.getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    BankRepository bankRepository = RepositoryFactory.getRepository(BankRepository.class);
    bankRepository.save(bank);
    bankRepository.flush();
    RepositoryFactory.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
}
```

A couple of things are wrong above, but I I've tried fixing it and can't:

1. Begin and Commit transactions are explicit.
2. `bankRepository` should be `@Autowired`, but when I do that I get `null`. However, in [this testcase](https://code.google.com/p/simple-cash/source/browse/trunk/src/test/java/com/simplecash/dal/repository/BankRepositoryTest.java?r=17) it is Autowired and works.

Has anyone faced a similar problem and knows what's going on?
Thanks a ton for taking the time to read this. Hope the answer to this question will help other folks.

Answer (score 3):

Both answer provided here offer good points (using injection to get the proxied beans and using transaction-annotations), however, I'm pretty sure that for the annotation-driven transactions to work (@Transactional), you need to add the following to your xml-configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Also make sure to add the tx-namespace in your beans-tag:

```
<beans
  <!-- SNIP, other namespaces -->
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  <!-- SNIP, other locations -->
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that in your setup the Transactions are managed by JTA, so you can't explicitly start/stop them (i.e. em.getTransaction().begin() will not work). Try telling Spring that you want a certain method to be part of a (JTA managed) transaction via annotation , like:

```
@Transactional
public void populateWithTestData() {
   //...    
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the `@Transactional` annotation, but didn't work. The code I have now (with explicit _begin_ and _commit_) works, but I think the repository's `save` already has the `@Transactional` attribute and I don't necessarily need it in my function (although I suppose I can add it). I think the problem lies either in the way I inject the `EntityManagerFactory` bean _or_ there's something missing in the application context's xml file..

Answer (score 2):

- *Begin and Commit transactions are explicit.*

What Spring does with your repository beans ( e.g. `BankRepository` ), it creates a proxy around it, and then it is ready to be *injected* into other collaborators, which in your case is `DatabaseManagerDAO`. However if you create the object yourself like you do:

```
BankRepository bankRepository = RepositoryFactory.getRepository(BankRepository.class);
```

Instead of expected Spring's proxy ( that already does transaction management for you ), you are getting a simple object that is not aware of anything beyond it is immediate declaration.

What you need to do instead is to *trust Spring* to do the plumbing for you and just inject a `bankRepository` bean into a `DatabaseManagerDAO` (although I don't really think you need both DAO and Repository, since those terms really mean the same thing :)

- *Repository Factory here, which I'm not sure if I need...*

No need for another abstraction. Just inject it as a bean to whatever component needs it.

- *`bankRepository` should be `@Autowired`, but when I do that I get `null`. However, in [this testcase](https://code.google.com/p/simple-cash/source/browse/trunk/src/test/java/com/simplecash/dal/repository/BankRepositoryTest.java?r=17) it is Autowired and works.*

In a case where [it works](https://code.google.com/p/simple-cash/source/browse/trunk/src/test/java/com/simplecash/dal/repository/BankRepositoryTest.java?r=17#25) you run your test with `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`, which *knows* about 'bankRepository' bean, hence autowires it. In your `DatabaseManagerDAO`, I see neither autowiring nor a setter for the `bankRepository`, in fact you create it manually from the factory.

#### *EDIT to answer comments*

What `jpa:repositories` in your XML config really does => it scans the package and creates Spring beans for each component that is either annotated as `@Repository` or implements a `Repository` interface.

With that in mind, what you should do in order to use a `BankRepository` repository in your `DatabaseManagerDAO` is to inject it. You can do it via "autowiring":

```
@Service
public class DatabaseManagerDAO {

    @Autowired
    BankRepository bankRepository;
    ... 
}
```

instead of manually creating it trough your factory.

Again, `DatabaseManagerDAO` in your case is probably a service ( `@Service` ), and not a `DAO`, but I'll leave it up to you to decide on that.

Notice that a `DatabaseManagerDAO` should also be loaded by Spring in order for the autowiring to work, so make sure it has one of the Spring annotations ( `@Service` / `@Component` ) when you package scan it ( e.g.  `<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>` ).

Comment: _"I see neither autowiring nor a setter for the bankRepository, in fact you create it manually from the factory"_.  I must be missing something basic here..  can you give me an example of a class and xml so I could have an injected instance of `BankRepository`?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when combining `spring-batch` and `spring-jpa`.  In my batch XML, I had this line:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager"/>
```

which caused an error since JPA needs a `PlatformTransactionManager`.