# Spring JPA Hibernate valid configuration not working with JdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, entitymanager, jdbctemplate

I do have a working configuration in Spring for JPA with Hibernate provider:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>
<bean id="jpaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>
```

This configuration is working in a small Spring based web-app.

But, when I insert the same configuration into an other existing Spring based web-app, I do get the following exception:

**javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress**

I think it has some conflict with Spring JDBC Templates:

```
<bean id="mysqlTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

How can I get this to work side by side?

Comment: see if the answers on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801828/hibernate-jpa-and-spring-javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-no-tran helps?

Comment: We found out the JdbcTemplate does not influence the JPA Hibernate. It is probably due to mis-configuration of the Spring ContextLoaderListener and DispatcherServlet. But what?

Comment: try to put property reference for entityManagerFactory inside jpaTransactionManager like: <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/> see if that the configurations missed

Answer (score 0):

"no transaction in progress" just means you're trying to use an EntityManager somewhere and you didn't start a transaction first. The stack trace will tell you exactly where that is. Since you're using annotation-driven transactions, just make sure you have an appropriate `@Transactional` somewhere up the call chain from the location where the exception is happening.

Comment: It works with `@Transactional` in the project without JdbcTemplate.
It does not work with `@Transactional` in the project with JdbcTemplate. I did try to set `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.XXX)` to all possible values. Everytime I got the same exception.

Comment: I said *appropriate* `@Transactional`. Most likely, you're operating within a transaction that was opened for the wrong data source, entity manager, or whatever.

Comment: I've created a seperate JNDI datasource in the Tomcat Context. There was a seperate transaction manager for each datasource. `@Transactional` was configured with the correct transaction manager and the `@PersistenceContext` was injected properly. I was able to read-only the database, I was able to auto-generate the tables, I'm not able to commit something in the database: the `entityManager.flush();` did throw the exception all the time.