# Hibernate JPA and Spring javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress (2)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactional

Again, the same problem, but the other answers given in the related posts don't help me.

Maven-formatted source code is at:

https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/my.bugs.smtpserver

```
git clone git@github.com:jjYBdx4IL/my.bugs.smtpserver.git
```

Exception thrown during "mvn test":

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:334)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.flush(Unknown Source)
    at my.bugs.smtpserver.MessageHookImpl.storeEMail(MessageHookImpl.java:46)
    at my.bugs.smtpserver.MessageHookImpl.onMessage(MessageHookImpl.java:30)
    at org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.DataLineMessageHookHandler.processExtensions(DataLineMessageHookHandler.java:128)
    at org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.DataLineMessageHookHandler.onLine(DataLineMessageHookHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.DataCmdHandler$DataLineFilterWrapper.onLine(DataCmdHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.DataCmdHandler$DataLineFilterWrapper.onLine(DataCmdHandler.java:67)
    at org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.SeparatingDataLineFilter.onBodyLine(SeparatingDataLineFilter.java:111)
    at org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.SeparatingDataLineFilter.onLine(SeparatingDataLineFilter.java:69)
    at org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.DataCmdHandler$DataLineFilterWrapper.onLine(DataCmdHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.DataCmdHandler$DataLineFilterWrapper.onLine(DataCmdHandler.java:67)
    at org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.esmtp.MailSizeEsmtpExtension.onLine(MailSizeEsmtpExtension.java:151)
    at org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.DataCmdHandler$DataLineFilterWrapper.onLine(DataCmdHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.DataCmdHandler$DataLineFilterWrapper.onLine(DataCmdHandler.java:67)
    at org.apache.james.protocols.netty.LineHandlerUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(LineHandlerUpstreamHandler.java:50)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.messageReceived(IdleStateHandler.java:270)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleUpstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:143)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:327)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:305)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:207)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:343)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:274)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate JPA and Spring javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801828/hibernate-jpa-and-spring-javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-no-tran)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your transactional method `storeEMail` is being directly invoke by `onMessage`.  The transactional behavior is implemented by a AOP proxy that wraps `storeEMail`.  Since you are invoking `storeEMail` directly, the AOP proxy isn't invoked and you don't have a transaction.  `storeEMail` needs to be invoked on an injected bean reference.  You may want to reconsider your design.

Comment: whoa, you are absolutely right.